# Echoing an multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This is my code:

```
$products = array(
array ("08:10", "10:30", "13:15"),
array ("GSÖ2B2U", "VSH2B2U", "FOR2B2U"), 
array ("GUS", "GJG", "GRL")
);
```

I'd like to be able to loop through this and receive the following output:

```
08:10 GSÖ2B2U GUS
10:30 VSH2B2U GJG
13:15 FOR2B2U GRL
```

I've tried looking for answers but I can't seem to find any, help appreciated :)

Comment: Show your current code/attempt

Comment: google `foreach in php`

Comment: `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value){` !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$products = array(
array ("08:10", "10:30", "13:15"),
array ("GSÖ2B2U", "VSH2B2U", "FOR2B2U"), 
array ("GUS", "GJG", "GRL")
);
$new= array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++) {
   $new[] = array_column($products, $i);
}

foreach($new as $vals) {
   echo implode(' ', $vals) . '<br>';
}
```

**Output**

```
08:10 GSÖ2B2U GUS<br>
10:30 VSH2B2U GJG<br>
13:15 FOR2B2U GRL<br>
```

Comment: why not `foreach(range(0, count($products)-1) as $i)
{
 echo $products[0][$i] . $products[1][$i] . $products[2][$i] . '<br>';
}` ?

Comment: @Viral What if the array element increases in both dimensions?

Comment: okay, this `foreach(range(0, $c = count($products)-1) as $i)
{
 foreach(range(0, $c) as $j)
 {
  echo $products[$j][$i] . ' ';
 }
 echo PHP_EOL;
}` @b0s3

Comment: @viral I dont think this code make the process any better. You sure?

Comment: but its easier to understand, just `foreach` and an $products array `count` !, so less processing cost @b0s3

Comment: @Viral, Hats off to you. :)